# How to convert multiple rows with same ID to single rows

Tags: r

I have a dataset1 which is as follows (table 1) :

```
structure(list(TCODE = c("T1", "T1", "T1", "T2", "T2", "T2", 
"T2", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T4"), MATERIAL = c("M105", 
"M100", "M102", "M345", "M400", "M100", "M220", "M260", "M400", 
"M390", "M400", "M100", "M700")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))

   TCODE MATERIAL
1     T1     M105
2     T1     M100
3     T1     M102
4     T2     M345
5     T2     M400
6     T2     M100
7     T2     M220
8     T2     M260
9     T3     M400
10    T4     M390
11    T4     M400
12    T4     M100
13    T4     M700
```

How to convert multiple rows into a single row based on first column?
The desired output is : table 2

**1     2       3       4       5**

**1**   M105,   M100,   M102

**2**   M345,   M400,   M100,   M220,   M260

**3**   M400

**4**   M390,   M400,   M100,   M700

Thanks.

Comment: It would be great if you could reply if any of the provided solutions work for you and then accept this answer so that others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df <- structure(list(TCODE = c("T1", "T1", "T1", "T2", "T2", "T2", 
"T2", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T4"), MATERIAL = c("M105", 
"M100", "M102", "M345", "M400", "M100", "M220", "M260", "M400", 
"M390", "M400", "M100", "M700")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))

library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(TCODE) %>%
  summarize(MATERIAL= paste0(MATERIAL, collapse = ', '))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  TCODE MATERIAL                    
  <chr> <chr>                       
1 T1    M105, M100, M102            
2 T2    M345, M400, M100, M220, M260
3 T3    M400                        
4 T4    M390, M400, M100, M700
```

---

If you want to have 5 columns, pivot_wider:

```
df %>%
  group_by(TCODE) %>%
  mutate(id = 1:n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(values_from = MATERIAL,
              names_from  = id,
              names_prefix = 'id_')

# A tibble: 4 x 6
  TCODE id_1  id_2  id_3  id_4  id_5 
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 T1    M105  M100  M102  <NA>  <NA> 
2 T2    M345  M400  M100  M220  M260 
3 T3    M400  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
4 T4    M390  M400  M100  M700  <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `toString` in `aggregate`.

```
aggregate(. ~ TCODE, dat, toString)
#   TCODE                     MATERIAL
# 1    T1             M105, M100, M102
# 2    T2 M345, M400, M100, M220, M260
# 3    T3                         M400
# 4    T4       M390, M400, M100, M700
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(TCODE = c("T1", "T1", "T1", "T2", "T2", "T2", 
"T2", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T4"), MATERIAL = c("M105", 
"M100", "M102", "M345", "M400", "M100", "M220", "M260", "M400", 
"M390", "M400", "M100", "M700")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We could do it this way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(TCODE) %>% 
  mutate(MATERIAL = toString(MATERIAL)) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  mutate(MATERIAL = str_split(MATERIAL, ', ')) %>% 
  unnest_wider(MATERIAL)
```

```
  TCODE ...1  ...2  ...3  ...4  ...5 
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 T1    M105  M100  M102  NA    NA   
2 T2    M345  M400  M100  M220  M260 
3 T3    M400  NA    NA    NA    NA   
4 T4    M390  M400  M100  M700  NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), TCODE ~ paste0("id_", rowid(TCODE)), value.var = 'MATERIAL')
```

-output

```
   TCODE   id_1   id_2   id_3   id_4   id_5
   <char> <char> <char> <char> <char> <char>
1:     T1   M105   M100   M102   <NA>   <NA>
2:     T2   M345   M400   M100   M220   M260
3:     T3   M400   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
4:     T4   M390   M400   M100   M700   <NA>
```